# How does one execute two different functions within the same custom module in Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible

I have created a custom ansible module in Python, and I'd like to use it this way:

**e2e.py**

```py
from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
​
​
def func_1(module):
    return module.params['var_1'], module.exit_json(changed=False, meta={'info': 'func_1'})
​
​
def func_2(module):
    var_1 = module.params['var_1']
    var_2, var_3 = module.params['var_2'], module.params['var_3']
​
    # use var_1, var_2 and var_3 here and return something
​
    return module.exit_json(changed=False, meta={'info': 'func_2'})
​
​
def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec={
        'var_1': {'type': 'str'},
        'var_2': {'type': 'str'},
        'var_3': {'type': 'str'}
    })
​
    var_1, resp = func_1(module)
​
    module.exit_json(changed=False, meta=resp)
    module.exit_json(changed=False, meta=func_2(module))
​
​
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**ansible-playbook**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
​
  tasks:
    - name: Func 1
      e2e:
        var_1: "var_1"
      register: func_1_resp
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ func_1_resp }}"
​
    - name: Func 2
      e2e:
        var_2: "var_2"
        var_3: "var_3"
      register: func_2_resp
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ func_2_resp }}"
```

The output I'm receiving is this one:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "var_1": null, 
            "var_2": "var_2", 
            "var_3": "var_3"
        }
    }, 
    "meta": {
        "info": "func_1"
    }
}

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: e2e.yml:18
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "meta": {
            "info": "func_1"
        }
    }
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

In my playbook I have two tasks `Func 1` and `Func 2` where I want to use my `e2e` module with different arguments (`var_1` for the first task and `var_2` & `var_3` for the second task). Even if I were to provide `var_1` to the second task's arguments list and vice-versa, the `module.exit_json(changed=False, meta=func_2(module))` would never be called.

How can I run both `func_1` and `func_2` with different arguments?

Comment: That's just a typo on my side, I edited that and it's the same error but with `var_1` instead of `var1` ^_^

Comment: @Zeitounator I say the problem and indeed I don't get that error. But func_1 is called twice (also in your example) instead of `func_1` and `func_2`. Will also edit my question. Edited

Comment: When (i.e. in which condition) do you want to return `func_1` in favor of `func_2` to calculate your module exit value ?

Comment: Well, in reality, I've separated my logic into functions so that each function will have its own task in ansible (so that I can output some messages for each of them). So it's really no condition. Think of it as several functions that have to be sequentially called... I'm not sure if I'm being clear...

Comment: I confirm this is not clear at all. If you don't want to exit the module, why do you call `module.exit` (btw the only one that is actually called is the one in func_1, not in your main). Just do the job you have to do, collect the info you have to collect, and return it once when everything is done and you exit the module.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific variable for each function, pass a value from Ansible, and write `if` block to call the particular function if the string matches. For example:

```py
if(action == "abc"):
    _json = fun_1(module)
elif(action == "xyz"):
    _json = fun_2(module)
```